# Can I validate graphQl query inside string with typescript?

Tags: typescript, graphql

I wrote query like this in my typescript file.

```
const query = `    
      query {
          transactions(
            filter: {
              now: { gt: ${gt}, lt: ${lt} }                
              account: {
                id: {
                  ${addr}
                }
              }
              balance_delta:{
                gt:"${amount}"             
              }  
            }
            orderBy: { path: "now", direction: DESC }
            limit: 1
          ) {
            id
            balance_delta(format: DEC)
            now
            account_addr
          }
        }`;
```

Can I validate (lint) it with typescript? Or suggest other methods ...